# What are the steps to host an asp.net 3.5 published website in iis 6.0?

Tags: asp.net, web, iis-6, publish

What are the steps to host an asp.net 3.5 published website in iis 6.0? Any suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a virtual directory in IIS, then use Visual Studio's Publish wizard to publish the site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure server has microsoft .net framework 3.5 (with sp1 recommended) runtime installed. Use [web deployment projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459) for deploying your asp.net application in single output assembly or use web publishing wizard for extract a release build. Make sure the build does not use debug configuration and it must be in release mode. Create a website or virtual diretory and configure it to run under asp.net 2.0. You will also need to define under which application pool the application shall run, it could be shared or isolated one. Copy your asp.net build to the root directory of the website or the virtual directory and you're good to go..